# Compile webpack on docker production server

Tags: docker, webpack, config, docker-compose

I am setting up docker for my React/Redux app, and I was wondering how to set it up in such way, that in production, on container setup, webpack compiles my whole code with production configuration, and then it removes itself, or something like that. Because the only thing I will need for my project is production code, and a simple node server that will serve it.

I'm not sure if I explained it well, since docker and webpack are still new things for me.

EDIT: 
Alternatively I can even serve everything with an apache server, but I want everything to compile and setup just when I run docker-compose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to trash your node dev dependencies from your image after your npm run build during the docker build.

You can do it but there is a little trick you must be aware of.
Each line in your Dockerfile result in a new step in the image and is pushed with the image.
So, if you execute in your Dockerfile :

```
RUN npm install     # Install dev and prod deps
RUN npm run build   # Execute your webpack build
RUN npm prune --production # Trash all devDependencies from your node_modules folder
```

Your image size will contains :

- The first npm install
- The npm run build
- The result of the npm prune

Your image will be bigger than just :

```
RUN npm install     # Install dev and prod deps
RUN npm run build   # Execute your webpack build
```

Wich contains :

- The first npm install
- The npm run build

To avoid this problem you must do in your dockerfile :

```
RUN npm install && npm run build && npm prune --production
```

That way you will get a minimalistic image. With :

- The npm run build
- The result of the npm prune

Your final Dockerfile will be some sort of :

```
FROM node:7.4.0

ADD . /src
RUN cd /src && npm install && npm run build && npm prune --production  # You can even use npm prune without the --production flag

ENV NODE_ENV production
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I needed. Do you also have and idea how could I serve created files later with Apache. To create sort of middleware container that just builds the code? Just exploring all the possibilities :)

Comment: I think that the best way to perform this is use volume-from in docker. You run a node container building webpack and execute the node server with -v flag to expose the folder where you build the public assets. Then an other docker container with --volume--from flag to get the folder accessible in the apache container. You just have to be sure your apache conf is getiing the assets from the mounted folder.

Comment: Example : `docker run -v /src/public -name my-node<your node container>` and : `docker run -volumes-from=my-node <your apache container>`